# SetPixel seem not work on some external window

Tags: c++, function-hooking

I have succefully hooked a game and I need to do read and write with GetPixel and SetPixel to the game window.

To do a test I have created this code:

Here my hooked function:

```
My_hooked_function(int a3)
{

    HWND hWnd = GetForegroundWindow();

    if (hWnd == NULL)
         hWnd = GetDesktopWindow();

    if (a3==49)
    {

        string buf;
        LF::Log_Update("Button Pressed");
        
        SetWindowLongA(hWnd, GWL_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)&WndProc);
        // SetWindowSubclass(hWnd, &WndProc, 1, 0);
        //DefSubclassProc
        // DrawPixels(hWnd);
    }
}
```

here my test function to draw something in the game (that is a old 32 bit that required directx 11):

```
void DrawPixels(HWND hwnd) {

    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    RECT r;

    LF::Log_Update("DrawPixels Entrato");

    GetClientRect(hwnd, &r);

    if (r.bottom == 0) {

        return;
    }

    HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {

        int x = rand() % r.right;
        int y = rand() % r.bottom;
        SetPixel(hdc, x, y, RGB(0, 0, 0));

        for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
        {
            SetPixel(hdc, x - i, y, RGB(0, 0, 0));
            SetPixel(hdc, x + -i, y, RGB(0, 0, 0));

            SetPixel(hdc, x, y + i, RGB(0, 0, 0));
            SetPixel(hdc, x, y - i, RGB(0, 0, 0));
        }

    }

    EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);

}
```

and here the window procedure callback:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg,
    WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {

    LF::Log_Update("Enter here");

    DrawPixels(hwnd);

    switch (msg) {

    case WM_PAINT:

        LF::Log_Update("For some reason not enter here");

        DrawPixels(hwnd);

        break;

    case WM_DESTROY:

        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }

return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
```

}

In my code I have 2 problems:

1. I need to attach and not replace the window procedure (SetWindowLongA is not right in this case) because the game must continue to work. I need only to paint some line to the game existing window.
2. I have tested the function "DrawPixels" to an empty c++ windows project and If I put it in the "WM_PAINT" message of the WndProc work perfectly but not in the game.

I searching for a way to draw some pixel on a external DirectX 11 game.

Can you help me please ?

Thanks !